Power Automate running Create Item twice after throttling
As the title suggests, my flow runs a create item twice when it should be ran only once. Basically I have an apply to each loop that goes through items and runs a create sharepoint item action, however this action is sometimes ran twice, and that is usually when the action is throttled by sharepoint and then reenabled. I don't know how else to explain it but that.

Basically Item 1 gets correctly added in the list,
Then Item 2 gets throttled for 5 minutes by sharepoint due to the high number of requests going to the site.
After 5 minutes, the item is created but it returns 2 id's higher then item 1.

When I check in the list, there are 2 of the same item that were created. Has anyone encountered this problem and if so how do i fix it?  Also no other flow is writing to this list at the same time so this is 100% why I just don't know how to fix this.
item 1

item 2

in sharepoint


Not exactly answering "why it happens", but you could create items in bulk to avoid such issue (that is most probably related to Power Automate throttling as you mentioned).
This blog post beautifully explains benefits and code to achieve. In short:

you can batch up to 1000 item creation per call;
author measured performance increase and reduced number of API calls by factor of 1000;
such calls can be executed in parallel (check concurrency control limitations in Power Automate);

Microsoft article on "Make batch requests" for more information.

I tried using the BATCH method in Power Automate and it didn't work for all of my data due to the Lookups and Person or Group columns so I was unfortunately forced to use this long and inefficient way. But I think the approach I will do is that if the data is incorrect try again until there are no duplicates. This is super inefficient but it's the only solution :(

Or you can pursue the batch way and post new question about lookup and people. Dream big, don't give up! ✌️
